# Unable to concatenate a varchar and ==

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-4

I am using postgresql 9
I am running a query to base64 decode a value and print its result:

```
SELECT convert_from(decode(CONCAT('aWFuY3VkYXRlc3QrMTAwQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ','=='),'base64'),'utf-8');
```

But, when I run the same query over the table, I get errors:
Version 1 of my query:

```
SELECT t.data,convert_from(decode(CONCAT(t.data,'=='),'base64'),'utf-8')
FROM table t;
```

The above gives me `ERROR:  unexpected "="` 
Version 2 of my query:

```
SELECT t.data,convert_from(decode(t.data,'base64'),'utf-8')
FROM table t;
```

The above gives me `ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x8c`

t.data is of datatype Varchar(255) in my table t.

I can't figure out how to fix this issue. Is there a different way to decode base64 data and print it out from a query?

Comment: do you have single or double quotes around this query string?

Comment: I don't have any type of quotes at all. I think it has to do with the length of t.data value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `||` instead `concat`:

```
SELECT convert_from(decode('aWFuY3VkYXRlc3QrMTAwQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ' || '==','base64'),'utf-8');
       convert_from        
---------------------------
 iancudatest+100@gmail.com
```

For table:

```
SELECT t.data,
       convert_from(decode(t.data::text || '==','base64'),'utf-8')
FROM table t;
```

Comment: **SELECT t.data,convert_from(decode(t.data.promo_code::text || '=','base64'),'utf-8') 
FROM table t;** is giving me the error unexpected "=". I think the length of the t.data value is different rows is causing the error.

Comment: Sorry - two `=` --> t.data::text || '=='

Comment: Thank you Roman, the issue was partly solved by your suggestion, but really, I had some records with less characters that were throwing errors.